# Table Relation Algorithm

Tags: sqlite

I've got a situation:

Two tables

```
country
    -countryID (PrimaryKey)
    -countryName
    -relativeToSubCountry (Foreign Key -> subCountry.subCountryID)

subCountry
    -subCountryID (PrimaryKey)
    -subCountryName
```

Example:

Germany is relative to more than one subcountry (period in history or independent state)

```
Germany -> Bavaria -> Saxonia -> ... -> Bismark -> Hitler -> BRD -> DDR
```

The question is how can I implement this table relations? Because `country.relativeToSubCountry` cannot to have more than 1 id.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: With your layout, each `country` can have only one `subCountry`. You'll have to either expand `subCountry` with a foreign key to other subcountries, or make each `country` potentially reference another country.

Comment: Thank you for your reply it was useful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each `subCountry` may only belong to a single `country`, then all you should need to do is move the foreign key:

```
country
    -countryID (PrimaryKey)
    -countryName

subCountry
    -subCountryID (PrimaryKey)
    -relativeToCountry (Foreign Key -> country.countryID)
    -subCountryName
```

Now each `subCountry` stores its "parent" and all `subCountry` rows for a `country` cxan be found by selecting for 'relativeToCountry`.

If the relationship is more complex (and historically I think it probably is, due to border changes) then you need a different structure again, something like

```
country
    -countryID (PrimaryKey)
    -countryName

subCountry
    -subCountryID (PrimaryKey)
    -subCountryName

subCountryStructure
    -relativeToCountry (Foreign Key -> country.countryID)
    -relativeToSubCountry (Foreign Key -> subCountry.subCountryID)
```

Now each `country` may have many `subCountry` records and vice versa. Further, information about each specific relationship (time period over which the relationship existed, for example) cxan be stored in the new table.

Comment: So, subCountryStructure is just a middle tier table?

Comment: All right, I've got this idea. It's really nice way. thank you.

Comment: There's one more question. Shouldn't I have an ID(PK) in my subCountryStructure?

Comment: @Nathan - depends if you're happy with compound primary keys. Or if the two keys in the structure table can be duplicated (say if a relationship existed twice in different periods and both needed a record of their own). Up to you...